# Lazy Loading not work in WebPack Angular 2 project

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I'm new to webPack and I have a problem with my project in Angular 2.

I'm trying to apply **Lazy Loading on the modules**, but I have always the same mistake for hours.

**The error occurs when i need to load a child module. (During the rooting)**

```
  export const routes: Routes =
[
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/account', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'account', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'student', canLoad: [AuthGuard],  loadChildren: './student.module/app.student.module#AppStudentModule' },
  { path: 'teacher', canLoad: [AuthGuard], loadChildren: './teacher.module/app.teacher.module#AppTeacherModule' },
  { path: 'administrative', canLoad: [AuthGuard], loadChildren: './secretary.module/app.secretary.module#AppSecretaryModule' },
  { path: 'unauthorized', component: PageUnauthorized },
  { path: 'terms', component: TermsComponent},
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFound }

];
```

I show you my current configuration:

My ***webpack.config.js***:

```
    const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeJsPlugin = require('optimize-js-plugin');
const StyleLintPlugin = require('stylelint-webpack-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const root = path.join.bind(path, path.resolve(__dirname));

// Webpack Config
const webpackConfig = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.ts',
    polyfills: './src/polyfills.ts',
    vendor: './src/vendor.ts'
  },

  output: {
    publicPath: '/public/js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/js')
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
      /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
      root('./src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes 
    ),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      'lodash': 'lodash',
      'moment': 'moment',
      'moment-timezone': 'moment-timezone',
      'angular2-mdl': 'angular2-mdl',
      'jquery': 'jquery'
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([ { from: 'src/assets/i18n', to: '/assets/i18n' } ]),
    
    new ExtractTextPlugin('../css/styles.css')   
  ],

  module: {
    loaders: [  
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: [
          'awesome-typescript-loader',
          'angular2-router-loader',
          'angular2-template-loader'
          
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: 'css-loader?minimize=true'
        }),
        include: [root('assets', 'css'), /node_modules/]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'raw-loader!sass-loader'    
      },  
      {test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader'},
      { test: /\.(png|jpg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|TTF|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
    ]
  }
};

const defaultConfig = {
  devtool: 'source-map',

  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].map',
    chunkFilename: '[name]-chunk.js'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.ts', '.js' ],
    modules: [ path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules') ]
  },

  node: {
    global: true,
    crypto: 'empty',
    __dirname: true,
    __filename: true,
    process: true,
    Buffer: false,
    clearImmediate: false,
    setImmediate: false
  }
};

const commonConfig = webpackMerge(defaultConfig, webpackConfig);

const prodConfig = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        sequences     : true,  // join consecutive statemets with the “comma operator”
        properties    : true,  // optimize property access: a["foo"] → a.foo
        dead_code     : true,  // discard unreachable code
        drop_debugger : true,  // discard “debugger” statements
        unsafe        : false, // some unsafe optimizations (see below)
        conditionals  : true,  // optimize if-s and conditional expressions
        comparisons   : true,  // optimize comparisons
        evaluate      : true,  // evaluate constant expressions
        booleans      : true,  // optimize boolean expressions
        loops         : true,  // optimize loops
        unused        : true,  // drop unused variables/functions
        hoist_funs    : true,  // hoist function declarations
        hoist_vars    : false, // hoist variable declarations
        if_return     : true,  // optimize if-s followed by return/continue
        join_vars     : true,  // join var declarations
        cascade       : true,  // try to cascade `right` into `left` in sequences
        side_effects  : true,  // drop side-effect-free statements
        warnings      : true,  // warn about potentially dangerous optimizations/code
      },
      output: {
        comments: false,
        space_colon: false
      }
    }),
    new OptimizeJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: false
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin()
  ]
};

const testConfig = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['raw-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'], exclude: [/\.global\.scss$/, /node_modules/]},
      {test: /\.global\.scss$/, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'], exclude: [/node_modules/]},
      {test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'], include: [/node_modules/]},
      {test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'], exclude: [/node_modules/]},
      {test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader'},
      {
        test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          mimetype: 'application/font-woff',
          name: '../fonts/[name].[ext]',
          publicPath: '/fonts/'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '../fonts/[name].[ext]',
          publicPath: '/fonts/'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
            query: {
              // use inline sourcemaps for "karma-remap-coverage" reporter
              sourceMap: false,
              inlineSourceMap: true,
              compilerOptions: {

                // Remove TypeScript helpers to be injected
                // below by DefinePlugin
                removeComments: true

              }
            },
          },
          'angular2-template-loader'
        ],
        exclude: [/\.e2e\.ts$/]
      },
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'source-map-loader',
        exclude: [/spec-bundle\.js/, /node_modules/]
      },
      {
        enforce: 'post',
        test: /\.(js|ts)$/,
        loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
        exclude: [
          /spec-bundle\.js/,
          /\.(e2e|spec)\.ts$/,
          /node_modules/
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};

const devConfig = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'tslint-loader',
        options: {
          configFile: 'tslint.json'
        },
        exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/, /node_modules/]
      },
    ]
  }
};


switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
  case 'staging':
  case 'production':
    module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, prodConfig);
    break;
  case 'test':
    module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, testConfig);
    break;
  case 'development':
  default:
    module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, devConfig);
}
```

And this is my ***tsconfig.json***:

```
    {
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "src/app.module#AppModule",
    "genDir": "./ngfactory",    
    "debug": false
  },
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "useWebpackText": true
  },
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "outDir": "public/js",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": ["node", "jasmine"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "public"
  ]
}
```

And so i have this error:
[image]

Please help me!!

Thanks

Comment: Do you have minimal project to reproduce it?

Comment: No sorry..i migrate my project from Systemjs to webPack. And the project is big.

Comment: `Unexpected token <` usually means that the response has wrong format

Comment: So do you mean that routing works fine?

Comment: Open `public/js0-chunk.js` directly in browser and check source code

Comment: I have been modify modify webpack confing:

`  output: {
    publicPath: '/public/js/',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/js/')
  },`


And
`output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].map',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunck.js',
    publicPath: "/"
  },
`

And still have same error: [https://imgur.com/a/K4xWx]

Comment: @yurzui The content of file is not visible..but is present in source.
[https://www.dropbox.com/s/q2ad1pag2o7ixij/Capture.PNG?dl=0]